# How do I display all rows from a table and count from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregation

I have a list of actors, and the goal is to show a count of how many "X" films the actors have played in, I also must display all the actors names regardless if they have played in "X" films or not.

Here are my tables for reference:

**ACTOR**
| A_ID
| A_FNAME
| A_LNAME
| A_YOB

**ROLE**
| A_ID
| M_ID
| R_ROLE

**MOVIE**
| M_ID
| M_NAME
| M_YOR

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT ALL A_FNAME, A_LNAME, COUNT(R_ROLE) AS "X FILMS"
 FROM ACTOR                                                  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE                                        
 ON ACTOR.A_ID = ROLE.A_ID                                   
 WHERE R_ROLE LIKE '%(X)%'                          
 GROUP BY A_FNAME, A_LNAME;
```

Which outputs only the actors who  have played in X films, however I need it to display all the actors I have inserted. How do I do this?

Comment: Which column hold the information of "X" film?

Comment: The R_ROLE column has the info of "X" film

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With subquery:

```
select  A_FNAME, A_LNAME,(select count(*) from role where role.a_id =a.a_id and  R_ROLE LIKE '%(X)%'  )from actor a
```

With join

```
SELECT ALL A_FNAME, A_LNAME,coalesce( COUNT(R_ROLE),0) AS "X FILMS"
 FROM ACTOR                                                  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from ROLE WHERE R_ROLE LIKE '%(X)%') r                          
 ON ACTOR.A_ID = r.A_ID                                   
 GROUP BY A_FNAME, A_LNAME;
```

Here coalesce() is used to replace null values with 0.